# Object Array data type

Tags: arangodb, foxx

This AQL returns an object I would like to use.

```
const keys = db._query(aql`
    FOR huis IN test
    FILTER huis._key in ${req.queryParams.keys}
    RETURN {
        'key': huis._key,
        'adres': huis.adres,
        'postcode': huis.postcode,
        'plaats': huis.plaats
    }
`);
```

This returns this object:

```
[
  {
    "key": "374875",
    "adres": "Klaverstraat 7",
    "postcode": "2197GV",
    "plaats": "Leiden"
  }
]
```

Then I would like to take the key like so:

```
keys[0].key
```

This works in JavaScript when I make a fiddle but not in Foxx.

```
const test = [
  {
    "key": "374875",
    "adres": "Klaverstraat 7",
    "postcode": "2197GV",
    "plaats": "Leiden"
  }
]

console.log(test[0].key)
```

> 374875

Why does this return 'undefined' in Foxx but the correct data in a Fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Foxx code:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  const test = [
    {
      "key": "374875",
      "adres": "Klaverstraat 7",
      "postcode": "2197GV",
      "plaats": "Leiden"
    }
  ];

  console.log(test[0].key);
  res.status(200).send(test[0]);
}, 'test1')
  .summary('test1')
  .description('test1');
```

Returns via REST:

```
{
  "key": "374875",
  "adres": "Klaverstraat 7",
  "postcode": "2197GV",
  "plaats": "Leiden"
}
```

Logs into the ArangoDB logs:

> 374875

When you are getting the data via a query, you need to make sure the query is completed before you read the contents of the result.

Look at this code:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  const keys = db._query(aql`
    FOR huis IN test
    FILTER huis._key == "374875"
    RETURN {
        'key': huis._key,
        'adres': huis.adres,
        'postcode': huis.postcode,
        'plaats': huis.plaats
    }
`).toArray();

  console.log(keys[0].key);

  res.status(200).send(keys);

}, 'test1')
  .summary('test1')
  .description('test1');
```

Here the `FILTER` condition has been changed, and `.toArray()` is added after the query has executed. This makes sure the query is complete and then the contents of `keys` is as you'd expect.

Comment: Forcing the query to return an array with `toArray()` works.